# Install Windows10 after Ubunutu 16.04 on SSD

Tags: dual-boot

Config : MSI laptop with FreeDos

I'd like to know if i can install Ubuntu first, then Windows 10 later on a SSD ?
With previous versions of Bios and Windows, it was impossible, and now ?

Thanks